# does connecting to full node via rpc over the public internet reveal your credentials?

Tags: bitcoin-core, security, json-rpc, full-node

While trying to connect to my full node, I accidentally entered my public ip address in the rpcconnect field of bitcoin.conf. Should I be worried that my  password is now out there and anyone can connect to my node via rpc? As a side note, the connection would not be successfull because I specify `rpcallowip` to only connect with local addresses.

```
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=password
rpcconnect=public_ip
```

Comment: Did you actually make a connection over the internet? (i.e., is `public_ip` equal to the IP of the machine you ran `bitcoin-cli` on?)

Comment: no it is a different machine on the same local network. I realized my mistake as soon as I entered the command, so I exited before I got a response.

Comment: If it's on another machine on the local network, the connection wouldn't go over the internet. So unless you don't trust your local network administration, I don't see an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credentials for the RPC interface are sent in cleartext, so anyone who was able to observe the packets containing that information would now know the username and password for the RPC interface of your node, as well as its IP address.